# Set IP address from VPN service (not from internet service provider) as main IP for server

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv4, tunneling

I’m currently trying to get 3-4 servers for our business, situed in our office, but the main problem for us is IPv4, as in Canada, ISP charge basically ~15$/month for a single IP.

It not really a huuge problem as if that the only option, we will opt for IP from ISP, but i’ve heard about IP tunneling as a possible way to literally subscribe for VPN service (to get the IPv4), and use the VPN IPv4, to set this IP (From VPN service) as the main IP for dedicated server (which is not situated in the same place, as VPN service will come from X and server are hosted in our office)

Is there some work arround to bring dedicated server outside world with IPv4 not coming from ISP (internet service where server are actually connect to)?

I’m a developper, not a network dude, so i really don’t know how internet work, and i realize my terrible lack of network knowledge, so i will greatly appreciate any help of any suggestion on how i can set an IPv4 to dedicated server, which IPv4 should not come from internet service provider as they charge high price, which is something i understand (not at this point) with the IPv4 situation.

Thanks alot

Comment: This is certainly not a reasonable business practice for IT management, so it is off topic. Reasonable practice would be to put those 3-4 servers on co-location or even virtualize into the cloud, or if they are really required to be on premises, that requirement perfectly justifies the price $15/month for a public static IP for them.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a networking expert either, but -

I don't think what you're asking is possible, because you need an Internet connection in order to route traffic from your server through the VPN service. That means you would need to pay for an IP anyway.

Maybe you could buy an extra router and pay for one IP address for the router, then connect the router to the VPN service and have your servers run through it. I'm not sure how much sense that makes, but it's a thought.

Comment: It's perfectly possible, though you need to set up advanced policy-based routing to achieve that. The problem is that the question is off topic on ServerFault.